# Executing MySQL to create stored procedures on Flask startup

Tags: python, mysql, flask

When I start my Flask app (and its HTTP server), I want it to read and execute a MySQL file (that happens to contain stored procedure definitions), before it even considers processing any URL routing, but I can't find out how to do this. @app.before_first_request requires a route to be accessed in order to run this initialisation function, so that's a non-starter for me.

My app starts out like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

# Create stored procedures from file
with open('stored_procedures.sql', 'r') as sql:
    procs = sql.read().split(';')
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    for proc in procs:            
        cursor.execute(proc)
    cursor.close()

# Lots of routing functions follow
```

When I start the app, the error I'm getting is:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

on the `cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()` line, which I assume means that the mysql hasn't 'initialised' yet, or something else I don't quite understand. If I leave out this initialisation function (and put all the stored procedures into the MySQL db by hand beforehand, everything works fine, including all the MySQL functions, so it's not a problem with the file's MySQL syntax, or any other app configuration issue as far as I can see.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `mysql.connection` returns `None` when it is unsuccessful in creating a connection. Since the code you've given looks to be right, I suspect the issue is less do to with the python code and more likely an issue in your config object or with the MySQL database.

Try connecting to your database using the mysql command line interface on the same computer with the same credentials you are trying to connect with in python.

- If unsuccessful, the error message given will be much more helpful in your search for a solution.
- If successful, the issue is probably in your `config` object. Verify that the config matches what you used to connect from the command line.

Comment: As I mentioned, without this SQL loading procedure, everything else works perfectly - all the routes and SQL lookups work as expected, so it's definitely not a problem with the DB setup. It must be something to do with the fact that the connection's just not available for a certain amount of time after Flask is up. What I'd like to see is a callback of some kind for the MySQL initialisation that says 'ready', and then I could run the script fine, I'm sure.